# Is there a javascript library that does spreadsheet calculations without the UI

Tags: javascript, excel, spreadsheet

I am working on a project that needs an excel like calculation engine in the browser. But, it doesn't need the grid UI.

Currently, I am able to do it by hiding the 'div' element of Handsontable. But, it isn't elegant. It is also a bit slow.

Is there a client side spreadsheet calculation library in javascript that does something like this?

```
x = [ [1, 2, "=A1+B1"],
      [2, "=SUM(A1,A2"),3] ];

y = CalculateJS(x);

##############
y: [[1, 2, 3], 
[2,3,3]]
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any (although I haven't really looked), but if you wish to implement your own, you could do something along these lines (heavily unoptimized, no error checking):

```
functions = {
    SUM: function(args) {
        var result = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
            result += parseInt(args[i]);
        }
        return result;
    }
};

function get_cell(position) {
    // This function returns the value of a cell at `position`
}

function parse_cell(position) {
    cell = get_cell(position);

    if (cell.length < 1 || cell[0] !== '=')
        return cell;

    return parse_token(cell.slice(1));
}

function parse_token(tok) {
    tok = tok.trim();

    if (tok.indexOf("(") < 0)
        return parse_cell(tok);

    var name = tok.slice(0, tok.indexOf("("));

    if (!(name in functions)) {
        return 0; // something better than this?
    }

    var arguments_tok = tok.slice(tok.indexOf("(") + 1);
    var arguments = [];

    while (true) {
        var arg_end = arguments_tok.indexOf(",");
        if (arg_end < 0) {
            arg_end = arguments_tok.lastIndexOf(")");
            if (arg_end < 0)
                break;
        }

        if (arguments_tok.indexOf("(") >= 0 && (arguments_tok.indexOf("(") < arg_end)) {
            var paren_amt = 1;
            arg_end = arguments_tok.indexOf("(") + 1;
            var end_tok = arguments_tok.slice(arguments_tok.indexOf("(") + 1);
            while (true) {
                if (paren_amt < 1) {
                    var last_index = end_tok.indexOf(",");
                    if (last_index < 0)
                        last_index = end_tok.indexOf(")");
                    arg_end += last_index;
                    end_tok = end_tok.slice(last_index);
                    break;
                }
                if (end_tok.indexOf("(") > 0 && (end_tok.indexOf("(") < end_tok.indexOf(")"))) {
                    paren_amt++;
                    arg_end += end_tok.indexOf("(") + 1;
                    end_tok = end_tok.slice(end_tok.indexOf("(") + 1);
                } else {
                    arg_end += end_tok.indexOf(")") + 1;
                    end_tok = end_tok.slice(end_tok.indexOf(")") + 1);
                    paren_amt--;
                }
            }
        }

        arguments.push(parse_token(arguments_tok.slice(0, arg_end)));

        arguments_tok = arguments_tok.slice(arg_end + 1);
    }

    return functions[name](arguments);
}
```

Hopefully this will give you a starting point!

To test in your browser, set `get_cell` to `function get_cell(x) {return x;}`, and then run `parse_cell("=SUM(5,SUM(1,7,SUM(8,111)),7,8)")`. It should result in `147` :)

Comment: Thanks @MiJyn. Parsing the formula is the easier of my problems. I'll use Handsontable's excellent ruleJS for that. A more complex issue is with optimizing the dependency tree. I am planning to use bacon.js. I'll post an update if i get it to work.

Comment: Optimizing the dependency tree, as in, caching the results?

Comment: I was referring to calculating cell values based on other cell values. I guess excel prepares a tree of such dependencies and traverses through that tree for each change. I am using bacon.js reactive approach for this now. I have a working program at  https://jsfiddle.net/sandeep_muthangi/3src81n3/56/. It doesn't work for excel formulae yet. All one has to do it to replace eval with ruleJS to get it to work for excel formulae.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to do this using bacon.js. It accounts for cell interdependencies. As of now, it calculates values for javascript formula instead of excel formula by using an eval function. To make it work for excel formulae, all one has to do is replace eval with Handsontable's ruleJS library. I couldn't find a URI for that library... hence eval.

https://jsfiddle.net/sandeep_muthangi/3src81n3/56/

```
var mx = [[1, 2, "A1+A2"],
        [2, "A2", "A3"]];

var output_reference_bus = {};

var re = /\$?[A-N]{1,2}\$?[1-9]{1,4}/ig
var alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".split('');

function convertToCellRef(rows, cols)   {
    var alphabet_index = rows+1, 
        abet = "";

  while (alphabet_index>0)  {
    abet = alphabet[alphabet_index%alphabet.length-1]+abet;
    alphabet_index = Math.floor(alphabet_index/alphabet.length);
  }

  return abet+(cols+1).toString();
}

function getAllReferences(value)    {
    if (typeof value != "string")
    return null;
  var references = value.match(re)
  if (references.length == 0)
    return null;
  return references;   
}

function replaceReferences(equation, args)  {
    var index = 0;
    return equation.replace(re, function(match, x, string)  {       
      return args[index++];
  });
}

//Assign an output bus to each cell
mx.forEach(function(row, row_index) {
    row.forEach(function(cell, cell_index)  {
    output_reference_bus[convertToCellRef(row_index, cell_index)] = Bacon.Bus();    
  })
})

//assign input buses based on cell references... and calculate the result when there is a value on all input buses
mx.forEach(function(row, row_index) {
    row.forEach(function(cell, cell_index)  {    
    if ((all_refs = getAllReferences(cell)) != null)    {

        var result = Bacon.combineAsArray(output_reference_bus[all_refs[0]]);

      for (i=1; i<all_refs.length; i++) {           
        result = Bacon.combineAsArray(result, output_reference_bus[all_refs[i]]);
      }

      result = result.map(function(data)    {           
            return eval(replaceReferences(cell, data));
      })      

      result.onValue(function(data) {
        console.log(convertToCellRef(row_index, cell_index), data);
        output_reference_bus[convertToCellRef(row_index, cell_index)].push(data);        
      });
    }

   else {
    if (typeof cell != "string")
      output_reference_bus[convertToCellRef(row_index, cell_index)].push(cell);          
    else        
      output_reference_bus[convertToCellRef(row_index, cell_index)].push(eval(cell));
   }
  })
})

output_reference_bus["A2"].push(20);
output_reference_bus["A1"].push(1);
output_reference_bus["A1"].push(50);
```